# Rename a sequence of files to a new sequence, keeping the suffix

Tags: powershell, rename

I need help to create a command in PowerShell to rename a sequence of files with this format:

> ```
> 001.jpg
> 001_1.jpg
> 002.jpg
> 002_1.jpg
> 003.jpg
> 003_1.jpg
> ```

into a new sequence that can start with a number such as 9612449, but keeping intact the suffixes, so new sequence would be:

> ```
> 9612449.jpg
> 9612449_1.jpg
> 9612450.jpg
> 9612450_1.jpg
> 9612451.jpg
> 9612451_1.jpg
> ```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried **yourself** already. Also add any error messages you may have encountered. This platform is all about helping people with their code..

Comment: Please regard, that this site is not a free code/script writing service! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask]! Once you have tried something on your own but failed, come back here, [edit] your post and provide a [mcve] of your coding attempts!

Comment: got it, and apologies... I´m not really a coder/programmer. Actually I run an auction company, and I have to provide photos in a sequence to be upload into the auction platform, owned by a 3rd party. The platform changed the software and now instead of using lot numbers, they require all photos to be named by item ID number. Oh well... I´ll try then to figure out something and will get back to you guys

Comment: It is always preferable to show one's effort. That said, even in the absence of such, to me a question is worth answering if it is well-defined and calls for a solution that may also be of interest to others. Note that unless you @-mention a specific user (which you can only do for one user at a time), they won't be notified of follow-up comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `9612449` is an *offset* to be added to the existing numbers that make up the first `_`-separated token or all of the base file names:

```
# Simulate a set of input files.
$files = [System.IO.FileInfo[]] (
  '001.jpg',
  '001_1.jpg',
  '002.jpg',
  '002_1.jpg',
  '003.jpg',
  '003_1.jpg'
)

# The number to offset the existing numbers by.
$offset = 9612449 - 1

# Process each file and apply the offset.
$files | ForEach-Object {
  # Split the base name into the number and the suffix.
  $num, $suffix = $_.BaseName -split '(?=_)', 2
  # Construct and output the new name, with the offset applied.
  '{0}{1}{2}' -f ($offset + $num), $suffix, $_.Extension
}
```

The above yields the output shown in your question.

---

Applied to a real file-renaming operation, you'd do something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath . -Filter *.jpg | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { 
    $num, $suffix = $_.BaseName -split '(?=_)', 2
    '{0}{1}{2}' -f ($offset + $num), $suffix, $_.Extension
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>